# How do i make a tree data structure that can hold two differnet generic types for parent and children

Tags: c#, generics, architecture

I am ashamed to admit that I am sitting on this problem for many many hours. But I just want to implement it the way I have it structured in the diagramm below....

I want to model the world with continents/countrys/states and citys in it. Each model has a reference to its parent and a list of references to its children except the world only has children (because there cant be a parent to it) and the city only has a parent-reference because it doesnt go deeper. (I want to implement it that for example "World" does not have a parent field, likewise "city" does not have a `List<Children>` field.

I was about to implement it in a tree data structure like following (I left out the implementations):
[image: Only interfaces shown for simplicity]

To give you an idea of the **code of the interfaces** I included the bare minimum of it here:

```
public interface IRoot<TChild>
{
    List<TChild> Children { get; set; }
    void AddChild(TChild child);
}
public interface ILeaf<TParent>
{
    TParent Parent { get; set; }
}
public interface INode<TParent, TChild> : IRoot<TChild>, ILeaf<TParent> { }
```

And a little **code of the implementation**:

```
public class Root<TChild> : IRoot<TChild>
{
    public List<TChild> Children { get; set; }
    public void AddChild(TChild child) { //... }
}
public class Leaf<TParent> : ILeaf<TParent>
{
    public TParent Parent { get; set; }
}
public class Node<TParent, TChild> : INode<TParent, TChild>
{
    private IRoot<TChild> root;
    private ILeaf<TParent> leaf;

    //...
}
```

Lastly the **code of the classes I want to structure**:

```
public class World : Root<Continent> { }
public class Continent : Node<World, Country> { }
public class Country : Node<Continent, State> { }
public class State : Node<Country, City> { }
public class City : Leaf<City> { }
```

**Here comes the Problem:**

Now to Add a child object in `Root<TChild>.AddChild(TChild)` I need to access `<TChlid>.Parent` so I would need to constraint the generic `TChild` to `ILeaf<IRoot<TChild>>` like this:

```
public class Root<TChild> : IRoot<TChild> where TChild : ILeaf<Root<TChild>>
{
    public void AddChild(TChild child)
    {
        child.Parent = this;
    }
}
```

But doing this, I get the Error

> CS0311  C# The type cannot be used as type parameter in the generic type or method. There is no implicit reference conversion from to.

At this line

```
public class World : Root<Continent> { }
```

Comment: How are `Root` and `Leaf` different from a `Node`? A root is a `Node` where the parent is null. A leaf is a `Node` where there is no reference to itself as a parent of another `Node`. If you simplify this, I believe your problem would at least be reduced.

Comment: `City` should have `State` as parent instead of `City`: `public class City : Leaf<State> { }`

Comment: Oliver, you are right I made a mistake in copying the code. The problem is still there tho.

Comment: Eliasar, a root object should be the same as a node, bit without the possibility of adding a parent. Because if everything were a node I would have to add two generic types for world. And there is no parent for world

Comment: The point is that the root would have a null as the parent in a tree structure anyway. You would need no type difference to show that. That's a value difference, not a structural difference.

Comment: Suppose we do your solution and we would discard root and leaf and only use node. How would you declare the classes world<tchild> and city<tparent>?

Comment: By not using Generics. You're explicitly stating that a Continent can only have Countries as children, and on down. Type does not need to be determined at runtime, because you already know which types can have parent-child relationships. I believe your problem is caused by working with a specific solution in mind.

Comment: To add to my previous comment, here's a [blog post by Eric Lippert](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser/) about why this pattern shouldn't be used as generics.

Comment: I suggest to create a generic and reusable `Tree<T>` collection completely decoupled from your specific problem. On the geography side I would declare an `IGeographicEntity` interface that the different geography classes implement. Then store your world in a `Tree<IGeographicEntity>`.

Comment: What if.... what if a year from now you're asked to add neighborhoods to the model? and then a year after that city blocks? What if you're asked to add the solar system, galaxy, universe? I would suggest, as Eliasar before me, to keep a single interface for `Node`, having the parent null for the root node and children collection null for the leaf nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have found a solution. It consists of making the base classes `Root<TChild>` and `Node<TParent, TChild>` abstract. Setting the parent of the child is delegated to an abstract method. In the concrete implementations, where the generic type parameters have been resolved, it is then no problem to access the `Parent` property.

I have also changed the interfaces slightly. Exposing the children as `List<TChild>` is problematic, as it allows anybody to circumvent the adding logic of `AddChild` by directly adding to the list and to forget to set the child's parent.

I also made the `Parent` property read-only in the interface, as the setter is only used in the implementation.

```
public interface IRoot<TChild>
{
    IReadOnlyList<TChild> Children { get; }
    void AddChild(TChild child);
}

public interface ILeaf<TParent>
{
    TParent Parent { get; }
}

public interface INode<TParent, TChild> : IRoot<TChild>, ILeaf<TParent>
{
}
```

The base classes:

```
public abstract class Root<TChild> : IRoot<TChild>
{
    private List<TChild> _children = new List<TChild>();
    public IReadOnlyList<TChild> Children => _children;

    public void AddChild(TChild child)
    {
        _children.Add(child);
        SetChildsParent(child);
    }

    protected abstract void SetChildsParent(TChild child);
}

public class Leaf<TParent> : ILeaf<TParent>
{
    public TParent Parent { get; internal set; }
}

public abstract class Node<TParent, TChild> : Root<TChild>, INode<TParent, TChild>
{
    public TParent Parent { get; internal set; }
}
```

Note that `Node` is inheriting from `Root`, thus we need only to supplement an `ILeaf` implementation.

The concrete implementation classes:

```
public class World : Root<Continent>
{
    protected override void SetChildsParent(Continent child) => child.Parent = this;
}

public class Continent : Node<World, Country>
{
    protected override void SetChildsParent(Country child) => child.Parent = this;
}

public class Country : Node<Continent, State>
{
    protected override void SetChildsParent(State child) => child.Parent = this;
}

public class State : Node<Country, City>
{
    protected override void SetChildsParent(City child) => child.Parent = this;
}

public class City : Leaf<State> { }
```